# Cocoa error 260, filepath structure

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa, file, ftp

I'm using this method

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
```

which gives a specific file url when I open a file in my app.  That url looks like

```
file://localhost/Users/User/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.0/Applications/229C1D14-28D4-4B82-8CBB-8B9BC472E7A3/Documents/Inbox/Trinity_2016-4.pdf
```

I'm trying to convert this from a file url to a path so I can use it with the open source library [SCRFTPRequest](https://github.com/Hackmodford/SCRFTPRequest).

The problem is I'm getting a cocoa error 260 when I try to point to a file, and I just want to make sure I'm setting this up correctly.

```
NSFileReadNoSuchFileError = 260,                        // Read error (no such file)
```

This is the example code

```
SCRFTPRequest *ftpRequest = [[SCRFTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://192.168.1.101/"] 
toUploadFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Info" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

And this is how I changed it

```
NSString *fileurl = @"file://Users/User....pdf";
NSString *path = [fileurl substringFromIndex:16];
SCRFTPRequest *ftpRequest = [[SCRFTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://192.168.1.101/"] 
toUploadFile:path];
```

Is this code formatted correctly?  As written it uses substringFromIndex to change the file url from file://localhost/Users/User... to /Users/User...

Comment: I do not know what SCRFTPRequest does, but if it takes a NSString it's probably expecting a path, not a file url.

Comment: [SCRFTPRequest](https://github.com/Hackmodford/SCRFTPRequest) So for the path, do I just drop the 'file://'?

Comment: I guessed it expects a path because the example code effectively passes it a path. Did you even try it? If it's an open source library why do you ask at all?  Just go and see what the code does with that argument. If you do not understand something in the code because it does something in a particular way, then ask a question related to understanding that particular thing.

Comment: So, I tried using stringFromIndex to make the string look like /Users/User...file.pdf and I am still getting error 260.  I'm just asking about how to format the path.  The NSBundle example had arrows around the path, like </Users/User...file.pdf>.  I also tried that with no luck.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about. What is `stringFromIndex`? Where had the example "arrows around the path"? What path are you actually using? The path `/Users/User...file.pdf` as written normally does not correspond to a real file on an OsX machine, so the error is correct as the file does not exist. WHat is the actual path of the file you want to upload?

Comment: Sorry, I meant substringFromIndex.  I added more detail, hopefully it explains more clearly what I'm trying to do.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DavisG. You're missing the correct index. Btw, don't bother directly manipulating strings, use NSURL - see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *fileurl = @"file://Users/User....pdf";
NSString *path = [fileurl substringFromIndex:16];
```

You're missing the correct index. This code doesn't make `path` be `/Users/User....pdf`, but rather `....pdf`. If there were no method to extract a path from an URL writing

```
NSString *path = [fileurl substringFromIndex:6];
```

would be sufficient. But, since we have the awesome NSURL class, there's **no excuse** for not wirting

```
NSURL *realURL = [NSURL URLWithString:fileurl];
NSString *path = [realURL path];
```

Comment: only the last one `[aURL path]` should ever be used to get the path for an `NSURL`

Comment: @uchuugaka Am I saying anything else?

Comment: sounds like you're saying substringFromIndex: would be sufficient, but it would not.

Comment: @uchuugaka "**If there were no method** to extract a path from an URL" - but there is, and I show that immediately afterwards. No need for splitting hair.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting the "no such file" error because you passed a file path that does not correspond to an actual file.

Try `NSLog`ging the pile path you are passing and verify that the file actually exists in the file sytem.